# setting com control's TYPEATTR in C#

Tags: c#, com, interop

i have converted a vb6 ocx to C# com control.
this com control is set up by the following:

```
[Guid("986067DA-F6C4-4C19-82ED-5D4DF1F54DB1")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
//Implementing interface that will be visible from PowerBuilder
[ProgId("Cmnd90.ACmnd")]
[ComVisible(true)]
```

when loading this com control in a vb6 application, it is shown correctly.
but the customer is using powerbuilder and it is not showing there. the customer said that in order for the com control to show in his application we need to set the control's TYPEFLAGS to TYPEFLAG_FCONTROL.
how can this be done in .NET?

Comment: That flag *hides* a type.  He probably meant the "Control" key in the registry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following decoration too :

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.TypeLibType(TypeLibTypeFlags.FControl)]
```

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.typelibtypeattribute.aspx

Comment: thanks. how can i check if an assembly is marked with the FControl flag?

Comment: You don't mark an assembly with this attribute but a class or interface. Using reflection should do the trick for that.

Comment: thanks, for some reason when investigating the tlb file i dont see the class marked with the FControl flag. the customer claims he needs the tlb to show the class is marked with FControl flag.